# Lose wallet access

Tags: wallet-recovery, dogecoin

how to detect the name of the wallet used with the address based on the address.I lost the smartphone.there the transfer of coin to my wallet address but I can not access the wallet caused by the absence of recovery phrase .. How to make the coin can be moved to my new address..merge already got to my old wallet

Comment: So to be clear: you lost the phone and do not have any backup of the phone, or any backup of the wallet that was on the phone?

Comment: Something off-topic: Dogecoin is a deprecated coin, should attempt to sold/use as much as possible afterward since there may be security risk related.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately without your backup phrase there is no way of getting access to your wallet. Your wallet is gone unless you find your phone.

See the point of a wallet (and the private key of the wallet) is to keep your coins yours. So **unless you own the private key, you don't own your coins**.

If you have your private key displayed and written down somewhere you can access your coins. If not forget it, there is no way to recover a lost wallet, without backup phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The point of phrase is to generate private key using words given by you. So inorder to own those lost coin you need that phrase .OR if you have ever noted your private key then you can still get back your coin else there is no such way.